# linux reset.h is missing while compiling

Tags: linux, debian, debian-based, orange-pi

I have Orange Pi PC with Armbian 5.20
I am trying to compile media_build with a DVB-T tuner firmware so the OS will recognize the device.
I need to compile the media_tree:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/CrazyCat/media_build
cd media_build
./build --main-git
```

The compilation is failed, here is the error:

```
/home/idan/media_build/v4l/sunxi-cir.c:26:25: fatal error: linux/reset.h: No such file or directory

 #include <linux/reset.h>

                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

full log: https://filetea.me/t1sG7ycnx8USqmKDrwFxtyEKA

Is it possible to fix this reset.h missing?

Comment: You need to install kernel headers and possibly tell the build system where they are located.

Comment: I have tried to install headers via this [guide](http://ask.xmodulo.com/install-kernel-headers-linux.html), terminal output: `Note, selecting 'linux-headers-sun8i' instead of 'linux-headers-3.4.112-sun8i'
linux-headers-sun8i is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.` 

What can I do next?